# The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: 'a'. Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the operation again

Tags: oledb

// e,g, I want to insert 3 columns in 1st row and 10 columns in rest of the rows
    //I am Creating excel file with sheet name as  MySheet
    // then updating value in 1st row, 1st cell of header as blank
    //then inserting data
    // Can anyone please help to insert data in excel without header

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName +
    ";Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=NO\"";

    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
    conn.Open();

    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [MySheet] (a string)";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [MySheet$] SET F1 = \"\"";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO  [MySheet] (a) values ('ABC')" //<-----Getting error to insert
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
    conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try [removed the (a)]

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO  [MySheet] values ('ABC')";
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error. There was a padded space ending column name in Excel. Removing that space from end of column name fixed the issue.